# Using $push within Array in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

i have an array inside my NetworkSchema which i am trying to update with another entry using **findOneandupdate** in mongoose

**My model**:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var NetworkSchema = new Schema({

UserID: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true
},
NetworkList: [{
    Fid: {

        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
}]});
```

**Html:**

```
<div ng-controller="AuthenticationController" style="margin-top: 50px">

<div ng-controller="NetworksController">
    <ul>

        <li ng-repeat="Network in Networkfriends">

            {{Network.firstName}}
            <button type="submit" class = "btn btn-default" data-ng-click="update(Network._id)">Add as a Friend</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="showlist()">show</button>
</div>
</div>
```

**Network Controller:**

```
$scope.update = function(FriendID)
    {
        var UserID = this.authentication.user._id;
        console.log('User ID :' +UserID);
        var NetworkList = [{

            Fid: this.FriendID
        }];

        $http.post('/networks/update',{UserID: UserID, FriendID: FriendID}, $scope.credentials).success(function(response){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

        });
}
```

**Network.Server.Controller:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    errorHandler = require('./errors.server.controller'),
    Network = mongoose.model('Network'),
    _ = require('lodash');
    util = require('util');

exports.update = function(req, res) {

var query={'UserID':req.body.UserID};


var NetworkList = [{Fid: req.body.FriendID}];
var update = {'NetworkList' :NetworkList};


Network.findOneAndUpdate(query,update,function(err){
    if (err) {
        return err;
    } else {
        NetworkList.push(req.body.FriendID);

    }
});
};
```

i want to add the objectID of user from **usersList** which i am getting from NetworkFriends in my HTML page as you can see above, whenever i click **Add as a Friend** button and what i am getting is a new entry in my database with ObjectID of NetworkFriend and i want comma separated objectID's of more than one NetworkFriend through **Add as a Friend** button

**Here is the entry in My Database**:

```
{
"NetworkList" : [ 
    {
        "Fid" : ObjectId("5486fab40bc27314276be8cf"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("548d6ed5d6994cac219f536f")
    }
],
"UserID" : "547eaaab6c39471c3f5aebb6",
"__v" : 0,
"_id" : ObjectId("548adbc8b7eac44013bf188d")
```

}

**My aim is:**

```
 {
"NetworkList" : [ 
    {
        "Fid" : ObjectId("5486fab40bc27314276be8cf"),"(objectID of another friend with comma separated like this"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("548d6ed5d6994cac219f536f")
    }
],
"UserID" : "547eaaab6c39471c3f5aebb6",
"__v" : 0,
"_id" : ObjectId("548adbc8b7eac44013bf188d")
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're aiming for isn't a valid structure.  What you likely want instead is a schema where `NetworkList` directly contains an array of ObjectIds of the user's friends:

```javascript
var NetworkSchema = new Schema({
    UserID: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    NetworkList: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }]
});
```

Your docs would then look like:

```javascript
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("548adbc8b7eac44013bf188d"),
    "NetworkList" : [ 
        ObjectId("5486fab40bc27314276be8cf") 
    ],
    "UserID" : "547eaaab6c39471c3f5aebb6",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Then you can add a new friend to `NetworkList` using the [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push) operator like this:

```javascript
exports.update = function(req, res) {
    var query={'UserID': req.body.UserID};
    var update = {$push: {'NetworkList': req.body.FriendID}};

    Network.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, function(err, doc){ ... });
};
```

Comment: A big Thanks for answer. But when i am trying your solution, ObjectID of user is going to server controller but not saving in my database, this is my findOneandUpdate 
Network.findOneAndUpdate(query,update,function(err){
  if (err) {
   return err;
  }
  else{
   console.log('hahahahaha');
  }
 });
can you tell me where i am going wrong?

Comment: Instead of `return err;`, call `console.log(err);` so you can see any errors.

Comment: it worked by using find and update separately, can you explain me how to use *post save* middleware in mongoose as i am trying to switch UserID and FriendID after save. i was trying to use

NetworkSchema.post('save',function(){
 NetworkSchema.find({'to': this.FriendID},function(err){
  if(err){
   return err;
  }
  
 });
 NetworkSchema.update({'from': this.UserID},function(err){
  if(err){
   return err;
  }

 });
 console.log('post save working');
});
It is now working for now can you suggest me where i am wrong

Comment: Glad you got it working.  It would be best to post the question about middleware as a new question.