# How to use the stop event on server side when all files are uploaded in jQuery File Upload

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I am using jQuery File Upload on express.js with jquery-file-upload-middleware and mongoose with mongoDB.

I want to upload images of a galery. The Galery object contains an array of Image objects, such as

```
var GalerySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    images: [ImageSchema]
})
```

After each file has been uploaded asynchronously, I want to push it into the images array of my Galery object.

I tried to do the following server side:

```
// Is called everytime an image is uploaded
upload.on('end', function(fileInfo, rew, res){
    // Get the galery
    db.Galery.findOne({_id: req.fields.galery_id}, function(err, galery){

        // Create new Image object instance
        var image = new db.Image({src: fileInfo.name});

        // Save, in order to create auto generated _id
        image.save(function(err){
            if(err) {console.log(err); return; }

            // Add to Images array of Galery object
            galery.images.push(image);

            // Save galery with added image
            galery.save(function(err){
                if(err) { console.log(err); return; }
            });
        })
    });
});
```

Doing that, I get a well known  `[VersionError: No matching document found.]`, that, to my current knowledge, is due to the simultaneous access of the same mongodb document, since the upload happens asynchronously.

So in order to deal with the asynchronous fashion of the problem, it would be great to wait for all the uploads to finish, and then to insert the images one by one into the mongodb i.e. using `async.parallel()`.

But how do I access the event of all uploads having been finished?

I know that browser side i can use the [stop event](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#stop). But first this does not contain any data about the uploaded files. Also, I want to do it the server-side.

Is there something like

```
upload.on('doneAll', function(allFilesInfo, req, res){...})?
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `res`? `res.end('Uploaded')`

Comment: I just found out a workaround by setting `sequentialUploads: true` in the jQuery File Upload properties, in order to upload one after another. Though, I would really like to know how to do it asynchronously.

Comment: I'm not sure which library you are using to get uploaded images. You need to know when the upload.on('end' for the last image gets called. Is there anyway to know that?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to fetch this event. The library I use is jquery-file-upload-middleware, as stated in the question. It is based on jQuery File Upload.

Comment: if the requests are seperate and independent for each upload, logically the server will not know (and shouldn't) if there are more files. Better soln is to make you client do an ajax/socket call after the uploads are complete, then this triggers a server route that does what you want at the server.

Comment: @Iceman your solution makes most sense. So in that case I would use the `stop` event on browser side. So how would you retrieve info about the uploaded image?

Comment: @Flaudre use a ticket based system. request a ticket and start image uploads. then when its over send a close ticket request with information about uploaded images from the front end. Sad bounty period is over ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use promises (Bluebird: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird, *npm install bluebird --save*) and have something like this:

```
var BPromise = require('bluebird');

var uploadDone = new BPromise(function (resolve, reject) {

    // your image upload

});

uploadDone.then(function (result) {

   // upload complete here

}, function (error) {
   console.log("Error: ", error);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question of **when** to resolve the promise, which is more or less what OP is wanting to know.

Answer (score 0):

Since jQuery File Upload is creating an XHR for each file, these are seen as separate POSTs on the server side and there's no direct way for the upload middleware to know when all uploads have finished. You could possibly create another endpoint to hit as a callback for the stop event, but that not only lacks information about what was uploaded, as you already know, but also isn't going to help much if two or more users happen to be uploading at the same time.

What I believe you need is to employ a [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) (or a [findByIdAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)) call to perform the update on `Galery`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27472002/866762) for an example of how to `$push` the `image` to `galery`.

Answer (score 0):

with the upload you are doing one request to the server per file or one request in total if you are using `sequentialUploads: true`. If you want to know when all the images were uploaded in an asyncronous scenario, you need to define an extra route with express and add a callback to the fileuploader when all files are finished that calls this route. Then you would also need to track which files were uploaded and not saved before. If your script is used by more than one person (public access?) then you will also need to implement some session handling to save what uploaded files to add when your "uploadDone" route is called. As you can see that is a lot of overhead, so i would advise using the `sequentialUploads: true` solution.

However I hardly believe that you get the `[VersionError: No matching document found.]` because of simultaneous access to the gallery document since getting / saving the document is a matter of few milliseconds. I would advice you to check if the `req.fields.galery_id` is sent.

```
console.log(req.fields.galery_id);
```